# Change Page owner in Wagtail admin

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

We have a Wagtail site where various people contribute to a news item before its published and the person who creates the page is not necessarily the main author. I'm looking for way to edit the `Page.owner` in the Wagtail admin.

In the model class I've added:

```py
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
       ...
       FieldPanel('owner')
    ]
```

Which shows all the site's users in a dropdown but this doesn't get saved. I was wondering if there was a more 'Wagtail' way of doing this, aside from overriding the `save()` definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did exactly the same thing as you did and the owner is saved without problems.

From what you wrote, it's difficult to understand why it's not saved.

Please don't hesitate to share more inputs.

Comment: You are right. I've tested my code and it now does work as expected. I wonder if there was a bug in the Wagtail core which a recent release fixed.

Comment: It is apparently not saved when you only save it as draft.